# PictureBox from file to BLOB to SQL Server database, then from DB to PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, blob, picturebox

I have 1 Windows Form with 1 pictureBox, 1 textBox, and 3 buttons: LoadFromFile, SaveToDB,  and LoadFromDB.

Using LINQ to SQL connection in App.config and next code in the form:

```
private void btnLoadFromFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// open file dialog
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
// image filters
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
// display image in picture box
picBox.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
// image file path
textBox1.Text = open.FileName;
}
}
```

I could load Picture and its path to form.

Now I need to save the picture to an image type field named `[BLOBData]` in my table: `tblBLOB (BLOBID, BLOBData)`. So what is the code to convert the picture to image type, and what is the code to then convert the image type to the picture to display it in the `PictureBox` control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store `Byte Array` as blob in DataBase. some useful conversion methods:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

---

store to DB:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // display image in picture box
    Image img = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    picBox.Image = img;
    // Byte Array that can store as BLOB in DB
    byte[] blobData = ImageToByteArray(img);
}
```

and load from DB:

```
picBox.Image = ByteArrayToImage(/* Byte Array of image from BLOB cell in DB */);
```

Comment: please do I need to replace imageIn by the Image name choosen in the OpenFileDialog() and byteArrayIn by the table field content ?

Comment: Many Thanks Ria, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: var qry = (from p in dc.tblBLOBs select p.BLOBData).FirstOrDefault();
            picBox.Image = ByteArrayToImage(qry); Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' to 'byte[]'   And Error: The best overloaded method match for 'MyNamespace.FrmPictureBox.ByteArrayToImage(byte[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @AlphaBird: Just use `.ToArray()`! `qry.ToArray()` resolved question?

Comment: Clear, short & hands-on response. Very useful, thanks a lot.